# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined on query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use the PHP MySQL PDO Database Class from [here](https://github.com/indieteq/indieteq-php-my-sql-pdo-database-class) to setting up my database connections and performing my query's. But the query like below keeps telling me that there's an error with one of the parameters.

> Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not
>   defined on query

```
$roles = $this->model->query("
   SELECT
      roles.name AS role_name,
      roles.description AS role_description,
      permissions.name AS permission_name,
      categories.name AS categorie_name
   FROM
      roles
      JOIN roles_permissions on roles_permissions.role_id
      JOIN permissions ON roles_permissions.permission_id = permissions.id
      JOIN categories ON categories.id = permissions.categorie_id
   WHERE
      roles_permissions.role_id = roles.id
      AND
      roles.name = :name
   ",
   array(
      "name" => $role
   )
);
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: That's a problem with a class you are using.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Don't use this class, use vanilla PDO instead.